# Input-methods in the insert eval expressions

Tags: input-method, eval-expression

I can activate the input method `french-azerty` by `M-x set-input-method RET french-azerty`. Then by a `qwerty` keyboard I can type like an `azerty` one. Thus typying `q` in the buffer gives `a`. But when I do `M-: (insert "q")` it gives `q` instead of `a`. Is there a way that the evaluations takes into account the chosen input-method? i.e. `M-: (insert "qwerty")` gives `azerty`?

Comment: @phils I would like to write inserting macros/functions which uses the full functionality of a specific input-method (e.g. french-azerty). But it seems that `insert` bypasses the input-method. When `french-azerty` is activated, typying `qwerty` in the buffer gives `azerty`. I don't underestand why `(insert "qwerty")` doesn't gives `azerty`? So how an insert-method insert a text? A related
[discussion][1] on SO allows to use an input method in minibuffer. 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169428/use-the-default-input-method-when-doing-an-incremental-search-in-evil

Comment: @phils If you are certain that an input-method cannot intervene when inserting, please convert your comments to an answer in order that I may be able to mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you evaluate `(insert "qwerty")` the *lisp reader* creates a string object with the literal value "qwerty". No input method functionality is able to intervene there.

The input method has already done its work by the time a character is inserted into a buffer, such that (using your example) typing <kbd>q</kbd> would result in `(insert "a")`, not `(insert "q")`.

`insert` itself is a very low-level function. The only manipulation that happens to its argument is to ensure that unibyte data is not inserted into a multibyte buffer, or vice versa.

However, if you're talking about *writing a function* to insert text into a buffer, there's absolutely no reason why you would need that sort of magic, because you'll be in a position to process the text however you wish *before* calling `insert`.